# SMS Delay (Samsung Galaxy S5 KLTE - SMG900F)

Tags: sms, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy S5 (SMG900F). The phone is rooted and I'm using a Team UB 5.0.2 Custom ROM.

I've noticed over the past couple of weeks that I've began to experience a considerable delay when receiving text (SMS) messages.

If I long-press on the message and check the timestamps it occasionally shows up as "Sent: 20:41, Received: 03:20." An important aside would be to mention that this only appears to happen at night. If I send myself some sample texts from another phone; they are received almost instantly.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues and found a viable solution?
 I'd also like to know if this is related to the ROM/Build, SIM Card, or whether it's purely down to the service provider (Virgin Media in this case).

Comment: I don't see what the device could have to do with that, nor how this might be Android related. The most likely cause indeed is your service provider, so I first would check with them (or other customers of the same, whether they have the same issues).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the reply. I was under the same kind of impression. It's just that I don't currently know enough about the build process etc. of custom ROMs and whether or not that could have some kind of effect on the "radio" ability. I'll give them a call later. Thanks for insight.

Comment: Though there theoretically could be delays caused by software (delayed sending on one end, or delay receiving), that's pretty unlikely – and especially unlikely to cause a gap that large. Coverage however could be one thing, or you having switched to airplane mode (if you turned reception of, it's clear you cannot receive ;) If you can rule out these two, and the gap is that large still, it must be something "on the way". *Eliminate all other factors, and the one which remains must be the truth.* (Sherlock Holmes, "The Sign of the Four")